# C# class inheritance with ScriptableObject UnityEvents and differently-typed UnityActions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, events

I'm creating custom UnityEvents for a game. The base class looks like this:

```
public class EventSO : ScriptableObject
{
    List<UnityAction> listeners = new List<UnityAction>();

    public virtual void Raise() { ... }
    public virtual void AddListener(UnityAction listener) { ... }
    public virtual void RemoveListener(UnityAction listener) { ... }
}
```

Sometimes I want to pass variables to an event. So I inherit:

```
public class FloatEventSO : EventSO
{
    List<UnityAction<float>> listeners = new List<UnityAction<float>>();

    public override void Raise(float f) { ... }
    public override void AddListener(UnityAction<float> listener) { ... }
    public override void RemoveListener(UnityAction<float> listener) { ... }
}
```

My goal is to be able to create ScriptableObjects for individual events I can then assign and invoke: a good example for a Float event might be to communicate game times. So, a ScriptableObject named "OnEveryHalfSec", for example.

The first problem with this approach is that I'll need to make a new class for each combination of variables passed to an event: UnityAction<float, int>, UnityAction<float, string>... and so on.

The second problem is that I can't override the base class like I've shown above; Raise(float) can't override Raise(). So I have to re-define on every class.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/generics/)!

Have a base class like e.g.

```
public abstract ParameterEventSO<T> : ScriptableObject
{
    List<UnityAction<T>> listeners = new List<UnityAction<T>>();

    public virtual void Raise(T value) 
    {
        foreach(var listener in listeners)
        {
            listener?.Invoke (value);
        }
    }
    public virtual void AddListener(UnityAction<T> listener)
    {
        listeners.Add(listener);
    }
    public virtual void RemoveListener(UnityAction<T> listener)
    {
        listeners.Remove(listener);
    }
}
```

Now you can have as many derived classes as you need with specific types like e.g.

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class FloatEvent : ParameterEventSO<float> { }
```

or

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class IntListEvent : ParameterEventSO<List<int>> { }
```

or also

```
public class CustomArgs
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public string Name;
    public DateTime TimeStamp;
}

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class CustomArgsEvent : ParameterEventSO<CustomArgs> { }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should define

```html
public override void Raise(float f) { ... }
```

as

```html
 public virtual void Raise(float f) { ... } in the base class
```

You didn't put "(float f)" in the base class

Comment: That would work if I only ever intended to extend to a float-carrying class, but what if I want a UnityEvent<int>? Then I need a Raise(float) and a Raise(int) in the base class. And so on for every permutation.

Comment: Maybe use generics, public virtual void Raise<T>(T value), and when you override, 
 public override void Raise<float>(float f) or something similar to replace the genric value of T

Comment: And if I wanted a UnityEvent<int, float>, create a new Raise<T1, T2>(T1 val1, T2 val2) method in the base, adding a new method each time I increase the number of arguments?

Comment: Yes you would have to create a new Raise<T> each time with however many arguments you want, like you said Raise<T1, T2>, or Raise<T1, T2, T3>, etc...